# Error publishing extensions in Visual Studio Code Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have read the [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xilV.png)  and follow the documentation steps. Keep publisher and Publishers id the same in package.json.

[Publishers id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWNmK.png)

[package.json publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtbKG.png)
The error message is shown in the following figure.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xilV.png)

Just like this I tried something else like a terminal

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13YIR.png)

I think I need help. Thank you!

Comment: what did you do to get the error, if you have a publisher id use `vsce` to set the publisher id for the next `vsce publish` command

Comment: I updated my question description to use terminal mode to publish the extension

Comment: no need to `package` the extension if you use `publish`, **Always** increase the version number if you publish, why do you post the same image twice, at least the content is the same. Create an issue at the VSC repo what could be the cause of this error. Don't use images, just use the text of the error message. The version number is `major.minor.patch` start with version numbering with `0.1.0` or `1.0.0`

Comment: I tried to increase the version number at release, but I still get this error :(

Comment: Create an issue at the VSC repo and ask what could be the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the "name" in package. json to avoid duplication
https://github.com/microsoft/vsmarketplace/issues/354